# Fullpage JS: prevent from snapping to top of section

Tags: fullpage.js

When I use Fullpage JS and scroll to the bottom of a section, the scroll bar snaps to the top of the section as soon as it is released.  How do you prevent this?  Here's a really simple example:

```
<body>

<ul id="menu">
<li class="active" data-menuanchor="firstPage"><a href="#firstPage">First slide</a></li>
<li data-menuanchor="secondPage"><a href="#secondPage">Second slide</a></li>
<li data-menuanchor="3rdPage"><a href="#3rdPage">Third slide</a></li>
<li data-menuanchor="4thPage"><a href="#4thPage">Fourth slide</a></li>
</ul>


<div id="fullpage">
<div class="section" id="section0" data-anchor="firstPage"><h1>Page One</h1></div>
<div class="section" id="section1" data-anchor="secondPage"><h1>Page Two</h1></div>
<div class="section" id="section2" data-anchor="3rdPage"><h1>Page Three</h1></div>
<div class="section" id="section3" data-anchor="4thPage"><h1>Page Four</h1></div>
</div>

<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
$('#fullpage').fullpage( {
autoScrolling: false,
anchors: ['firstPage', 'secondPage', '3rdPage', '4thPage'],
menu: '#menu',
sectionsColor: ['#1bbc9b', '#4BBFC3', '#7BAABE', '#000'],
});
});


</script>


</body>
</html>
```

On the developer's sample page, the snapping doesn't occur, but I'm not sure why:
http://alvarotrigo.com/fullPage/examples/normalScroll.html

Comment: What version are you using of fullPage.js

Comment: I'm using version 2.3.6

Comment: Are you talking about the use of fullPage.js on mobile phones? Or on desktop?

Comment: I'm talking about desktop.

Comment: Download the latest version `2.4.8.1` and let me know if you still having troubles.